# How to Autorotate subview in iOS6?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS6, autorotate is different from previous version, because it should be worked with UINavigation. I have a View_A with UINavigation bar and it pushViewController:View_B and View_B pushViewController:C. So View_A, View_B and View_C all can autorotate. My question is if in View_C I use addsubview to add View_D as subview, View_D don't autorotate. I don't know how to autorotate subview in iOS 6. Did someone have the same question with me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 -  (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

            if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
         // do the UI changes

            }
         if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape){
         // do UI changes 
           }

return YES;

}
```

Comment: You can change your subviews according to your orientation with above code and it will work on iOS 6